# Is there a way to make it so windows gives me a popup when I run my program with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I am working on a piece of software that takes the line of text you put in data.json then measures how many characters are in it with the .length, is there a way I can make it so it will give me a popup with the length result so I don't have to have it in console?

Here is my current code

length.js

```
const text = require('./data.json').text;
const textchar = (`${text}`.length);
let equal = ('1');
let truefalse = (equal < text)
console.log('=====================');

if (truefalse) {
    console.log(`["${text}" has ${textchar} character]`)
} else {
    console.log(`"${text}" has ${textchar} characters`)
}
//equal === text
console.log('=====================');
```

data.json

```
{
    "text": "t"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-notifier` npm package in what you are looking for.